# Controlling the operation of aws lambda(python 3.6)

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I have a lambda that is coded in python 3.6 with some SQL queries in it to parse to aws Athena. This lambda will be triggered by a dynamoDB whenever there is a new item that falls into dynamodb. For each new item, I want to spin up a lambda. For suppose, if there are 100 new items that fall into DynamoDB- there will be 100 concurrent Lambda that will execute. But in this process, there was a moment where one of the SQL query failed in Athena and lambda cannot complete the calculation for that dynamodb record.

Note: the data of each record in dynamodb will be parsed to SQL queries in python and to AWS ATHENA.

My question: When there is an error in one of the concurrent Lambda's how do I stop this process, the lambda is repeating the execution for the same record which is costing me.

Comment: I am not asking about errors or code, I just want to know how to stop the lambda when there is a failure in the execution.

Comment: Are you using a synchronous `RequestResponse` invocation type or aysnchronous `event` invocation of lambda functions?

Comment: It is not synchronous RequestResponse. When a new record is generated/edited in the DynamoDB, the lambda starts executing for that record. When there are 100 records generated in DynamoDB, lambda is running one by one for each record. When a record fails execution, it is rerunning for the same record.

Answer (score 0):

Lambdas triggering from stream based sources, such as DynamoDB, are designed to continue retrying the same record over and over again until it expires (24 hours) or it succeeds. You simply need to catch the error at the code level and ensure that it doesn't bubble all the way up outside of your handler. Using some example code for a python lambda handling a DynamoDB stream event, you just need to wrap whatever is raising the exception in your handling function in a `try-except`.

```
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    for record in event['Records']:
        try:
            # suppose this method can throw an exception
            process_record_with_athena(record)
        except Exception as e:
            print("Caught exception {0} processing record: {1}. Ignoring and continuing...".format(e, record)) 
    print('Successfully processed %s records.' % str(len(event['Records'])))
```

You'll also want to watch out for timeouts. If your lambda is timing out while processing a batch of records from DynamoDB, then it will also continue to retry that batch over and over. You can see if you are getting a timeout in the logs in CloudWatch.

As a side note, just because you have 100 new items inserted into DynamoDB, that doesn't mean that you'll have 100 lambdas executing concurrently. Those 100 items could easily all be partitioned into the same stream shard, which would then mean that you only have one lambda processing all of them.

Comment: Thank you so much, In regards to your side note, Can you please tell me how to spin up concurrent lambdas?